# Matching arbitrary url to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi everyone
I am trying to do configure routes.rb to allow me to do the following mapping:

```
/links/quick/"arbitrary comment"/"http://www.arbitrary-site.com/test?a=1"
```

to `links#quick (LinksController.quick)?`

I came from django and is used to using regex to do this kind of mapping. Does rails have something equivalent? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html does not mention anything like that nor is the IRC helpful.

Comment: Just letting you know that you might want to improve your accept rating. Other users might shy away from someone who has a low score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have a route and pass in additional parameters then usually you would use a syntax like:

`match '/links/quick/:comment/:url/test' => controller`

The parameters denoted with a colon are called segment keys and they will accept whatever value you put in them. You then can access these segment keys in your controller by calling params[:segment_key] (Where the :segment_key is the name of *your* segment key) 
You can however filter whats accepted by using segment constraints. For example if you just wanted to accept an integer in the :comment parameter you would write:

`match '/links/quick/:comment/:url/test' => controller, :constraints => {:comment => /\d+/}`

It is important to know that the regular expression anchors at both ends so it wouldn't accept something like `string99withanumber`

For more information on segment constraints see this [link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).

Comment: How come the url /links/quick/"http://www.arbitrary-site.com/test?a=1", is not matching '/links/quick/:site'?

Comment: The addition of the / is messing that up. try using *site (no colon) which will grab everything after the /